# How to add a second static link block in footer (Magento2)?

Tags: magento2, static-block, footer, footer-links

Currently I only have 1 static block with footer links.

[image]

I would like to have a second one like in the image below (image is from magento1.9) I would also like to add a "title" to the footer link block like in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a cms block with your links( for example block name is linkstwo).
2. Go to

   > Admin -> CONTENT -> Widgets -> Add new Widget->
   >
   > Type       -> "Static Block"
   >
   > Design theme -> Luma
   >
   > CONTINUE
   >
   > Storefront Properties -> Layout Updates -> All pages AND container -> Cms footer links
   >
   > Widget Options -> Select a block (in your case linkstwo)

Save the widget, remove the cache and check.

Comment: Hey man! Thanks alot, this worked so far. Now the CSS seems to be messed up and the footer link blocks arent side by side.. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

if you are creating a new theme, which would be the best approach, then you could just simply override the file:
Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

in that file inside your theme, you can put this xml code:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer.static.block">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">your_static_block_id</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

More info in extending a layout file here 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-extend.html

Answer (score 0):

To add a second static link block in footer in Magento 2, follow these steps:

1. Create a new static block: Go to Content > Blocks in the Magento 2 admin panel and click on "Add New Block". Fill in the required fields for your new static block, including a unique identifier, title, and content. Save the block.
2. Create a new widget instance: Go to Content > Widgets and click on "Add Widget". Select the "CMS Static Block" widget type and click on "Continue".
3. Configure the widget instance: Choose a unique widget title, select the store view where you want the new link block to appear, and choose the "Footer" container from the "Layout Updates" section.
4. Select the new static block: Under the "Widget Options" section, select the new static block that you created in step 1 from the "CMS Static Block" dropdown menu.
5. Save and check your website: Click on "Save" to save your new widget instance, and then check your website to see the new link block in the footer.